# Icon is not exported from react-icons and compiler error is shown

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-icons

I installed react-icons but it is not working

error: FaBeer not exported

````
import '../style/mobHeader.css'
import { FaBeer } from 'react-icons/fa';
const Mobileheader = () => {
    return (
        <div className="mob-header">
            <h3>LoremIPSUM</h3>
            <h3>LoremIPSUM </h3>
            <FaBeer />
   
        </div>
    );
}```
````

Comment: your import syntax looks fine, you should check that the package was installed successfully, can you find the package in you modules folder?

Comment: Yes, package is there..I checked it in node_modules

Answer (score 1):

Been having this problem since yesterday too. Seems to be something to do with the newest version (v4.3.0).

You can install the previous version (v4.2.0) for now until a proper solution is found using:

```
npm install react-icons@4.2.0 --save
```